# TaskRouter event-parsing in callback API

Tags: spring-boot, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-taskrouter

I have set the callback URL to one of my controller methods in spring boot application. But I'm unable to understand how to parse the events being sent to this method. I figured there are two ways to do this.

**Note**: End goal is to map each event type (task, worker, etc) to their respective POJOs that I've created in the application.

1. Using request.getParameterMap(). I reckon this would require to iterate over each key and use my POJO's setters to set the values.

```
    @PostMapping(value="event/twilio")
    public void eventCallback(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Logger.info("Event payload: " + request.getParameterMap());
    }
```

2. Accepting String body in the method itself. The `eventPayload` appears to be an Urlencoded value rather than a json string.

```
    @PostMapping(value="event/twilio")
    public void eventCallback(@RequestBody String eventPayload) {
        Logger.info("Event payload: " + eventPayload);
    }
```